# Pelican - not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pelican

Fisrt creating a simple static page with pelican. Everything worked fine until i change the theme to `basic theme`. Locally is running fine, but i try to execute `make github` or `make publish` i'm getting this error:

> CRITICAL: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>   Makefile:75: recipe for target 'publish' failed
>   make: *** [publish] Error 1

I installed theme as the documentation said, but it its not working.
Below is my pelicanconf.py

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
from __future__ import unicode_literals

AUTHOR = 'Isaac'
SITENAME = 'Isaac's blog'
SITEURL = ''

PATH = 'content'

TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

DEFAULT_LANG = 'en'

# Feed generation is usually not desired when developing
FEED_ALL_ATOM = None
CATEGORY_FEED_ATOM = None
TRANSLATION_FEED_ATOM = None
AUTHOR_FEED_ATOM = None
AUTHOR_FEED_RSS = None

# Blogroll
LINKS = (('Pelican', 'http://getpelican.com/'),
         ('Python.org', 'http://python.org/'),
         ('Jinja2', 'http://jinja.pocoo.org/'),
         ('You can modify those links in your config file', '#'),)

# Social widget
SOCIAL = (('You can add links in your config file', '#'),
          ('Another social link', '#'),)

DEFAULT_PAGINATION = 10

THEME='basic'



# Uncomment following line if you want document-relative URLs when developing
RELATIVE_URLS = True
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting and find the error on line `SITENAME = `...

Comment: The SO formatting shows that `SITENAME = 'Isaac's blog'` is a blatant issue because you now have unbalanced single quotes. Change to `SITENAME = "Isaac's blog"`, with double quotes. If that's your actual file, this is a typo.

Comment: @roganjosh True! My I forgot to edit the name when i paste it here, but actually i have the name SITENAME = "Isaac's blog", so this is not the problem.

Comment: It's not the name, it's the mix of quotation marks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to base.html file, which is usually in templates folder of any theme. Then find '|format(' and replace it with '.format(slug=' without quotes. That should fix the error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting."

In other words, turn

```
{{ CATEGORY_FEED_ATOM|format(category.slug) }}
```

into

```
{{ CATEGORY_FEED_ATOM.format(slug='category.slug') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the apostrophe in SITENAME
So change:

```
    SITENAME = 'Isaac's blog'
```

to:

```
    SITENAME = 'Isaac\'s blog'
```

or, even easier

```
    SITENAME = "Isaac's blog"
```

Comment: Actually I just leave the name as 'Isaac' but still not working. If a change the theme to the pelican's default them it is published fine.